# Pairwise set intersection of 2 Pandas Series of 2 different Pandas dataframes in order without merging

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, set-intersection

I have 2 Pandas dataframe and I want to find the length of the intersection of 2 columns in order. For example:

```
    df1 = 

 a           b
 a1          b1
 a2          b2
 a3          b3

  df2 =
 a           b
 a1          b1
 a4          b4
 a2          b4



 Answer: 1  only 1 pair is in common (a1.  b1)
```

For 1 column, I can simply write:

```
 set(df1.a).intersection(set(df2.a))
```

How to do this for 2 columns without merging the 2 data frames and is it possible?

EDIT: **I want it without merging**

Comment: Ok, I see. I also upvoted the answer. It is no problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `merge`:

```
df1.merge(df2, on=['a','b'])
```

Output:

```
    a   b
0  a1  b1
```